# Give the names of employees who earn more than their manager

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
EMPNO   ENAME   JOB         MGR     HIREDATE    SAL     COMM    DEPTNO

7369    SMITH   CLERK       7902    2000-12-17  800     Null        20

7902    FORD    ANALYST     7566    1992-12-03  3000    Null        20
```

Hi guys, I have this type of table, and I need to show the employees who earn more than there managers? It would be easier if we had 2 tables, but I cannot imagine a code within one table. Any ideas?

Comment: As per your sample data, there will not be any employee having salary more than manager. Please ensure that you have a minimal sample data covering atleast the case you want to achieve, and corresponding expected output.

Comment: Hint:  self-join.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You can do "self-join" between the two tables. In the second table, `EMPNO` will be equal to the corresponding `MGR` value.
- Use `Where` to filter out cases where salary of employee is higher than that of manager.

Try:

```
SELECT employee.*
FROM your_table_name AS employee
JOIN your_table_name AS manager ON manager.EMPNO = employee.MGR 
WHERE employee.SAL > manager.SAL
```

---

As *@Strawberry* [suggested in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52793563/sql-give-the-names-of-employees-who-earn-more-than-their-manager/52793580?noredirect=1#comment92508535_52793580) that column comparisons can be done in the join condition itself (instead of using `Where`). You can do the following as well:

```
SELECT employee.*
FROM your_table_name AS employee
JOIN your_table_name AS manager ON manager.EMPNO = employee.MGR AND 
                                   employee.SAL > manager.SAL
```

The advantage of this approach is that we have to switch from Inner Join to Left Join, changes required to the query would be lesser.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I was trying to implement it for 2 days! And I have an additional question which I guess is about understanding the sql logic. I need to give the hierarchy of the company, could you advice something about it?

Comment: @AzatAleksanyan that is a very complex problem, involving Recusive Hierarchical query. Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query

Comment: @AzatAleksanyan I would suggest you to build hierarchy in application code (eg: PHP) instead

Comment: For column comparisons, I prefer AND to WHERE

Comment: @Strawberry why so ? Is it because join will bring less data for where to filter ? I believe both would use indexes though.

Comment: @madhurbhaiya I think because there's less to change when switching from inner join to left join

Comment: @Strawberry updated answer to include your suggestion as well :)

Answer (score 0):

you should use self join

```
SELECT e1.EMPNO, e1.ENAME
FROM employee e1
JOIN employee mgr ON mgr.EMPNO = e1.MGR 
WHERE e1.SAL > mgr.SAL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select name as Employee 
    from Employee as t
    where salary > (select salary from Employee where id=t.ManagerId);
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.